# Slow query performance when searching for a particular value, but fast with a different value on the same column

Tags: sql-server, sql-like, query-performance, database-indexes

have a SQL Server 2017 select statement that is executed by the front end application. The query has three joins and UNION. Each Join statement has a clause where `NAME LIKE '%ibm%'`

But when I change '%ibm%' to `NAME LIKE %services%` is runs fast as usual.

I rebuilt all the indexes on all of the tables and created missing statistics on the columns. This has not changed anything in the query performance.

Comment: When you have a leading wildcard like that the indexes are rendered helpless. Your query is nonSARGable so performance is going to be a challenge.

Answer (score 1):

The performance (depending on the exact query also) would depend on the specific value in the LIKE.

As the amount of times the specific query is returning a success for the specific value (LIKE is true), is going to increase the number of rows in the joins/union.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying here. But the number of rows being returned isn't the performance issue.

Comment: I also used SET TIME STATISTICS AND IO STATISTICS and there was no so much of big difference in terms of number of reads except one table.

Comment: The final number of rows is not a performance issue, but if in a query you are doing a subquery,  or a join or a union before giving the final result that's affecting the performance, and that's why (according to the question) it changes depending on the value